# Remove a style from style-m

Tags: css, less

this style is causing an issue with my mobile menu.

```
  .navigation .submenu:not(:first-child).expanded {
    display: block !Important;
  }
```

I have tried to overwrite it but it still appears as a duplicate. Is it possible to remove this completely from my theme.

I am trying to replace the rule with

```
  .navigation .submenu:not(:first-child).expanded {
    display: none;
  }
```

I cant use none !important because that then breaks something else. So thats why i need to remove it completly

Comment: When you say it appears as a duplicate, do you mean that it exists as an overwritten rule when you inspect that element, or is it actually being applied instead of your overwrite?

Comment: It will just exist as another rule. I am trying to completly change the rule to

  .navigation .submenu:not(:first-child).expanded {
    display: none;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must overwrite this path:

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_navigation.less
```

in line **196** is the CSS code is causing you problems... :)

Comment: Thank you! you have fixed a week long headache

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to copy style-m.css to your theme and delete the desired line of code. Example: Vendor / Theme / web / css / style-m.css , That way it is completely removed.